# the use of Cartesian product

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am currently studying in secondery level. I read cartesian product the other day and I found it absolutely bizarre. In my text book, there is this "order pair" which I understood fairly well and then there is cartesian product in which we multiply two sets. I don't understand the concept behind it. What is its application? How will it come to use in higher level study?

Comment: The number of application is very very huge. I think the best way to find out how it comes to use is not a list. If you go on with your study then you will engage these things automatically. Study them thoroughly and as a result of that the answer to your question will get more and more profile.

Comment: Every mathematics course at university will use the Cartesian product. It will also be present in every statistics course, many computer science courses, physics courses.

Answer (score 6):

The basic point of set theory in mathematics is that it allows us to wrap up *properties* and treat them as if they were *things*.

Without sets we can say things like

> $2.5$ is a rational number.
>
> $\pi$ is not a rational number.
>
> $36$ is a perfect square.
>
> $(0,42)$ is an ordered pair of two whole numbers.

The wordings "is a rational number", "is a perfect square", "is an ordered pair of two whole numbers" denote *properties*. They are nice for talking about particular things that have or don't have the property. But our language doesn't allow us to speak about, for example, an expression whose value is a *property*, or a function that takes a *property* as input or things like that.

This is where sets come in. A set is a way to "box up" a property such that it becomes a "thing" that we can speak about *together with* other similar things. To a large extent, a property and a set are different ways of thinking about the same concept. If we have a property, say "is a thingamajig" we can always (with some technical exceptions that you don't need to worry about at this level) create a set from it: $$A=\{x\mid x\text{ is a thingamajig}\}$$
On the other hand, whenever we have a name or an expression for a set, this gives us a property: "is a member of such-and-such set".

Because sets are "things", they can have (or not have) properties themselves -- such as the property "is a set of real numbers (but possibly not all the real numbers)". Boxing up these properties, we get sets of sets and so forth.

Now the cartesian product $A\times B$ is neither more nor less than the set corresponding to the *property* "is an ordered pair of something from $A$ and something from $B$".

Thus, whenever we want to speak about ordered pairs *at all*, it may suddenly become useful to speak about the *property* of being an ordered pair. And then it immediately becomes useful to speak about the boxed-up property that corresponds to it. In fact so useful that the *common* way to say "is an ordered pair of something from $A$ and something from $B$" is "is in $A\times B$". This is shorter and more concise.

So cartesian products are used, or potentially used, *everywhere* we use ordered pairs in the first place.

Comment: It's amazing what one can get upvotes for.

Answer (score 1):

The Cartesian product of $2$ sets $A$ and $B$ is just the set of all ordered pairs $(a,b)$ where $a \in A$ and $b \in B$. You can think of it as creating a set of from 2 other sets. For example $A = B = \mathbb{R} => A\times B = \mathbb{R}^{2}$. Put two real number lines perpendicular to each other and you get the xy-plane. Another example is $A=\{6,8\}, B=\{1,2,5\} => A \times B = \{(a,b)\}$ where a could be either 6 or 8 and b could be 1, 2 or 5. Thus an element of $A\times B$ could be $(6,2)$, but not $(8,7)$ since $7$ is not in $B$.

To answer: 'How will it come to use in higher level study?'

Some branches of mathematics use "The Axiom of Choice" which is equivalent to "the cartesian product of a collection of non-empty sets is non-empty". Said Axiom is used in measure theory to prove that there exists sets that cannot be "measured".

Comment: Bringing the axiom of choice into this discussion is like talking about quantum mechanics when someone asks you what is the reaction between hydrogen and oxygen when we apply heat.

Comment: @AsafKaragila That's why I was explaining to what it was equivalent?

Comment: @AsafKaragila 'How will it come to use in higher level study?'

Comment: @AsafKaragila edited!

Answer (score 1):

If you understand what ordered pairs are, then understanding the Cartesian product is not very difficult.

Given two sets $A$ and $B$ are, their Cartesian product, denoted by $A\times B$, is a new set whose elements are all the ordered pairs $(a,b)$ where $a\in A$ and $b\in B$.

For example if $A=\{0,1\}$ and $B=\{x\}$, then $A\times B=\{(0,x),(1,x)\}$. We took all the possible combinations.

What are its applications? Many. When $A$ and $B$ have additional structure of "the same type" we can often amalgamate these structures to endow $A\times B$ with a structure of that type as well, in a way which extends naturally the structure of $A$ and $B$.

This includes groups, rings, topological spaces, and many more.

In modern mathematics relations, and in particular functions, can be modeled as subsets of Cartesian products of sets, all of which make this notion incredibly important.

Answer (score 0):

A few applications I can think of (details below)

- Theory of computation: Finite Automata
- Computer Science: Databases
- Discrete Numbers: Domain of Operators
- Linear Algebra: Indexing: Matrix indices
- Combinatorics: All possible enumerations to compose an object from k categories of attributes

In theory of computation, it is used to convert a parallel non-deterministic finite automata to a sequential deterministic finite automata by growing the number of state space of the DFA to be the cartesian product of all individual DFA's state spaces as each parallel NFA can be viewed as a union of multiple DFAs.

In databases, we have a few attributes (e.g. gender, sexuality) , each attribute has a finite number of categories (e.g. (male or female), (straight or gay)). We want to know the largest size of the database containing distinct combination these attributes {(male, straight), (male, gay), (female, straight), (female, gay).  Cartesian product enumerates all possible combination of these attributes. Finitary relation can then be thought of as a subset of this cartesian product. It indicates if a particular combination exists in our database. Whenever we query a database with lots of information, we are really seeking for a subset of the cartesian product that matches whatever conditional restriction filter we pass it in. Example is if a company wants to figure out if there are any (male, gay) employees in their company, they would query for that filter in their database.

The entire logic behind querying a database is encapsulated into the field called relational algebra (performing algebra with finitary relations).
Hence, cartesian product is also used there (particularly when joining 2 different tables in a database)

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finitary_relation
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)#Cross_join

Another application is to think of it as representing a domain for an operator which takes in 2 inputs, 1 of category A and another of category B and outputs category C.
You would define the operator to be a mapping from (the cartesian product of A and B) to C

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_operation#Terminology

Another way is to think of a matrix (2 sets) with different number of rows and columns. All the different indices pairs in the matrix is the cartesian product between the indices for the row and the indices for the column. This also generalize to indexing for higher dimensions (called tensors)

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indexed_family
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product#A_two-dimensional_coordinate_system
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor

Finally, it can also be thought of as all the enumerations for composing objects (such as a deck of cards) from few categories of attributes (13 ranks and 4suits = 52 distinct cards)

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product#A_deck_of_cards

Answer (score -2):

also i just got to learn that we use set cartesian products in combinatorial problems .An example of this is a three course meal where there is an appetiser main course and desert.Lets say for example we have porridge,soup,lemonade and main course chicken,omlades,cooked potatoes,and desert icecream fruitpoodingand chocolate one can have soup,chicken,chocolate or soup,omlates,fruitpooding etc thus such is an example of application of set cartesian product